# How to implement global accesed screens with bottom tab navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm developing an application whose main navigation is composed by [bottom tabs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/), this application has some screens which need to be globally accesed from different tabs/places. An important thing to highlight is that from this global screen I can go back to the place from which it was accessed(go back navigation action). Here a simple UI to ilustrate the use case:

[image]

It's not clear to me how the distribution of the navigators must be to be able to implement this navigation architecture.

Comment: Are you using react-router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can go is **Nest bottom tabs navigator inside a stack navigator**

and put the global screens inside the stack navigator

something like this :

```
function bottomTabNavigator() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={bottomTabNavigator}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="GlobalScreen" component={GloballyAccessedScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    
  );
}
```

for the second part of your question ,  to go back you should use `navigation.goBack();`